# "Uncaught Error: Module name "gcm" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a phonegap application which is using Google Cloud Messaging, I have taken this code snippet from [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gcm) , I have downloaded require.js from [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#requirejs) and I have put it in a project's directory ,when sendToGoogleCloud() function is executed then It throws following error :

> "Uncaught Error: Module name "gcm" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

I couldn't figure out what the problem was also I am not familiar about require() .
Here is code snippet:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"> </script>
        <script data-main="main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


     //other functions will go here 

     function sendToGoogleCloud() 
     {
            var GCM = require('gcm').GCM;
            var apiKey = 'my api key';
            var gcm = new GCM(apiKey);

            var message = {
                registration_id: 'android device registration id', // required
                collapse_key: 'Collapse key', 
                'data.key1': 'value1',
                'data.key2': 'value2'
            };

            gcm.send(message, function(err, messageId){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
                } else {
                    console.log("Sent with message ID: ", messageId);
                }
            });
     }

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

     </script>
    <input id="sendtogooglecloud" type = "button"      onclick="sendToGoogleCloud()" value="Send To GoogleCloud">
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: <input> tag attributes are not proper.

Comment: I have fixed this ,even I am facing same issue .

Comment: Can you update here in your post ?

Comment: I have updated this .

Comment: I will be helpful if you share line number of this error here?

Comment: ok , It is "var gcm = new GCM(apiKey)" in function sendToGoogleCloud() .

Comment: I have updated question title and code snippent both .

Answer (score 0):

Order need to be :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> 
    //..... Remaining js libreries
```

Also, onDeviceReady callback function missing  it seems!

Comment: I have updated this, still I am facing same problem .

Comment: No, onDeviceReday() is there but I haven't put it here .

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"> </script>
```

to this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"> </script>
```

---

And your input type button have some weird attributes:

```
<input id="sendtogooglecloud" type = "button" Send To GoogleCloud"      onclick="sendToGoogleCloud()" value="Send To GoogleCloud">
//--------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--this above--.
```

---

Just noticed your `jQuery version 2.0` jQuery mobile version `1.3.2` doesnot work with it, so change your jQuery library to 1.9+ branch, not sure with 1.10+.

Comment: Jquery version 2.0 is working with JQuerymobile-1.3.2.js in some other phonegap applications .So think it should work here .

Answer (score 0):

Your require call doesn't look correct. The define call is, as far as I know, async, so your `GCM` variable will stay undefined in the `sendToGoogleCloud` function.
I have never work with GCM, so I don't know what the correct way of implementing it is, but you can try this:

```
function sendToGoogleCloud() {
    require(["gcm"], function (GCM) {
        var apiKey = "my api key";
        var gcm = new GCM(apiKey);

        var message = {
            registration_id: "android device registration id"
        };

        gcm.send(message, function(err, messageId) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Sent with message ID: ", messageId);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion is helpfull . I have tried this and I am getting a new error message "Uncaught Error: Script error for: gcm "

Comment: This can have a couple of reasons. Maybe "gcm" is not the correct module name. Where does your 3rd party code come from?

Comment: Okay. You're using code that's made for Node.js (server) and not cordova (client). So it will never work. You need to find another way to integrate, what you want.

Comment: Thanks @jonas for suggesting me . I think https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova will be better way to implement gcm over phonegap .